# Place input and buttons on one line

Tags: html, css

I have got one html and one css file. There are below.

```css
main {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list-lists {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.list-lists h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--grey);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#lists .single-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--darkest);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#lists .single-list .f {
  display: inline
}

.single-list .f .content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.single-list .f .content .text {
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.single-list .f .content .text:not(:read-only) {
  color: var(--pink);
}

.single-list .f .actions {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.single-list .f .actions button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.single-list .f .actions button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.single-list .f .actions button:active {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.single-list .f .actions .edit {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink), var(--purple));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.single-list .f .actions .delete {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="list-lists">
    <div id="lists">
      <div class="single-list">

        <form class="f" method="POST" action="">
          <div class="content">
            <input type="text" class="text" value="Hi" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

The problem is that input and buttons at the end of a page displayed on separate lines.

[image: what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1fgW.png)

And I want them to be on the same line.

[image: what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L94jz.png)

Result on the second image achieved by deleting form tag and removing its reference in css file. But I need to preserve it.

Comment: do you want `edit` and `delete` to be inside the `<input>`-element itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `inline-block` to the elements `actions` and `content` would put them in one line:

```
.single-list .f .actions {
    /* display: flex; */ 
    margin: 0 -0.5rem;
 }

.content, .actions {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

```css
 main {
        flex: 1 1 0%;
        max-width: 800px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .list-lists {
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .list-lists h2 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: var(--grey);
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      #lists .single-list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background-color: var(--darkest);
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      #lists .single-list .f {
        display: inline;
      }

      .single-list .f .content {
        flex: 1 1 0%;
      }

      .single-list .f .content .text {
        color: var(--light);
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.4s;
      }

      .single-list .f .content .text:not(:read-only) {
        color: var(--pink);
      }

      .single-list .f .actions {
        /* display: flex; */
        margin: 0 -0.5rem;
      }

      .single-list .f .actions button {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 0 0.5rem;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        transition: 0.4s;
      }

      .single-list .f .actions button:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }

      .single-list .f .actions button:active {
        opacity: 0.6;
      }

      .single-list .f .actions .edit {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink), var(--purple));
        /*-webkit-background-clip: text;*/
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      }

      .single-list .f .actions .delete {
        color: crimson;
      }
      .content,
      .actions {
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<main>
      <section class="list-lists">
        <div id="lists">
          <div class="single-list">
            <form class="f" method="POST" action="">
              <div class="content">
                <input type="text" class="text" value="Hi" readonly />
              </div>

              <div class="actions">
                <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                <button class="delete">Delete</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: At the begging I thought It works, but then I noticed that it actually works because I commented out <form> tag. But I cannot delete the <form> tag.

Comment: @John That's strange, works fom me just with those changes, I've not commented out the form tag.

Comment: Yeah, Now I figured it out and was able to apply your solution properly.